# XSLT: Behavior of key() inside predicate

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to get the nodes from a nodeset which are not included in a different nodeset.

first nodeset

```
<suppressingEvent event="x">
    <suppressedEvent event="a"/>
    <suppressedEvent event="b"/>
    <suppressedEvent event="c"/>
</suppressingEvent>
```

second nodeset

```
<suppressingEvent event="y">
    <suppressedEvent event="a"/>
    <suppressedEvent event="b"/>
    <suppressedEvent event="c"/>
    <suppressedEvent event="d"/>
</suppressingEvent>
```

Thus I want to get `<suppressedEvent event="d"/>`

First I filter the second nodeset for the `suppressedEvent` nodes of the first nodeset with a key and store these in the variable `sameSuppressedEvents`.

```
<xsl:variable name="sameSuppressedEvents" select="key('suppressedEventsFromSuppressingEvent', $suppressingEvent/suppressedEvent/@event, .)"/>
```

Then I want to store the remaining `<suppressedEvent event="d"/>` in the variable `otherSuppressedEvents`. But the predicate `[not($sameSuppressedEvents)]` does not work.

```
<xsl:variable name="otherSuppressedEvents" select="./suppressedEvent[not($sameSuppressedEvents)]"/>
```

But when I use directly the key inside the predicate I get the desired output.

```
<xsl:variable name="otherSuppressedEvents" select="./suppressedEvent[not(key('suppressedEventsFromSuppressingEvent', $suppressingEvent/suppressedEvent/@event, .))]"/>
```

Why does it behave like this?

And what is `<xsl:variable name="otherSuppressedEvents" select="./suppressedEvent[not($sameSuppressedEvents)]"/>` actually doing? Obviously not returning the unequal `suppressedEvent` nodes.

Is there a general way to compare two variables which are holding a nodeset and returning just the nodes which are unique in the nodeset which is under investigation?

Full stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" media-type="application/xml" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <FIDandFIC>           
            <xsl:apply-templates select="FiMrelations/suppressingEvent"/>
        </FIDandFIC>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="suppressingEvent">
        <FIC>
            <xsl:attribute name="event">
                <xsl:value-of select="./@event"/>
            </xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:attribute name="fatal">
                <xsl:value-of select="./@fatal"/>
            </xsl:attribute>

            <!-- Take all other suppressingEvent nodes to compare the underlying suppressedEvent Nodes with the ones from this current suppressingEvent -->
            <!-- If the underlying suppressed Events are the same then you can combine these suppressing Events to one FID -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../suppressingEvent" mode="equalFID">
                <xsl:with-param name="suppressingEvent" select="."/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>

        </FIC>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:key name="suppressedEventsFromSuppressingEvent" match="suppressedEvent" use="./@event"/>

    <xsl:template match="suppressingEvent" mode="equalFID">
        <xsl:param name="suppressingEvent"/> 

        <xsl:if test="count($suppressingEvent/suppressedEvent) = count(./suppressedEvent)">
            <xsl:variable name="sameSuppressedEvents" select="key('suppressedEventsFromSuppressingEvent', $suppressingEvent/suppressedEvent/@event, .)"/>        

            <xsl:variable name="otherSuppressedEvents" select="./suppressedEvent[not(key('suppressedEventsFromSuppressingEvent', $suppressingEvent/suppressedEvent/@event, .))]"/>

            <!-- this does not work -->            
            <!-- <xsl:variable name="otherSuppressedEvents" select="./suppressedEvent[not($sameSuppressedEvents)]"/> -->

            <xsl:if test="not($otherSuppressedEvents)">
                <equalFID>
                    <xsl:attribute name="suppressingEvent">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./@event"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <xsl:attribute name="OBD-Relevant">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./@OBD-Relevant"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <xsl:attribute name="fatal">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./@fatal"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </equalFID>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if> 

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of the key() function with "." as the third argument is going to depend on the value of ".", which is different inside a predicate, so it's not surprising that the two cases are different.

In the first case you haven't told us what the context node is when you call key(). In the second case it's clear that it's a `suppressedEvent` element, which makes the call very dubious since key() will only search within the subtree rooted at the node supplied in the 3rd argument.

Comment: The context node of the first case when I call key() is the second nodeset. Thus I get all nodes of this second nodeset which are as well included in the first nodeset, which means a, b and c and not d.

Comment: Following @Michaels explanation, this means for the second case, that key() is actually just searching through the one `suppressedEvent` node and checks if this one node has an equal partner in the first nodeset. And this will be done in the variable statement for every `suppressedEvent` node, so in this example the key() function is executed 4 times. Am I right?